# Why am I getting an admobs error No Ad to show?

Tags: admob, ads

I'm attempting to add admobs ads to my mobile app. The app has launched and originally was showing ads. A couple days later it stopped showing ads and I now get the error

"error": "Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show.}"

When I put in a testing adUnitId I will get a test ad.

The production adUnitId is older than 2 weeks and was working at one point. My payment information and all other account information is up to date.

I am unable to link my app in admobs, as it won't show up when searching for it (my other apps will show up when searching by developer, but not this app). Not sure if that is part of the problem or not, but thought I should mention it.